# $\det(I+A\bar{A}) \ge 0$ for all complex square matrices $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\det(I+A\bar{A}) \ge 0$

Is it possible to prove the inequality is true for all complex square matrices $A$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $\bar{A}$ is the complex conjugated matrix.

Comment: I've think I've checked that it's true for $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Comment: I wrote a few lines of sage to produce many random examples, and the conjecture seems to hold.  Even $det(A\bar{A}) \geq 0$ seems to hold.

Comment: @StevenGubkin I also tried a few in mathematica. The proof seems more difficult than I initially thought. I am not even sure if I am qualified enough to answer this.

Comment: @Rzeta, numerically it appears that the eigenvalues of $A\bar{A}$ are coming in conjugate pairs.  This might help with an avenue to the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigenvalues of $A\bar{A}$ have been thoroughly studied in

> D.C. Youla, [A normal form for a matrix under the unitary congruence group](http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1961-059-8), *Canad. J. Math.* 13(1961), 694-704.

In the paper, it is proved (in Lemma 5) that for any complex square matrix $A$, those eigenvalues of $A\bar{A}$ that are not real nonnegative must either be

- non-real and occur in conjugate pairs, or
- real, negative and have even multiplicities (so they also occur in "conjugate pairs").

It follows immediately that $\det(I+A\bar{A})$ is real nonnegative.

Answer (score 3):

Really it is a very difficult question dated 1980-81 (Am. Math. Monthly). Personally I did not find any solution. The simplest method is as follows.

EDIT.

1. Show the result when $A\bar{A}$ has no negative eigenvalues.
2. Show that the multiplicity of a negative eigenvalue of $A\bar{A}$ cannot be $1$.
3. Show that the set of matrices $A$ that satisfy 1. is dense in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.
4. Conclude.

Comment: I can do 1. How do you do 2?

Comment: @  user208259 , give your proof of 1. Clearly 2. is the essential question....

Comment: For any two matrices $A$ and $B$, the matrices $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial. When $B = \overline{A}$, this shows that the characteristic polynomial of $A\overline{A}$ is equal to its own conjugate, and therefore has real coefficients. If we write $f(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I + A\overline{A})$, it is clear that $f(0) = |\det A|^2 \geq 0$. If we had $f(1) < 0$, then since $f$ is real, by the intermediate value theorem we'd have a root $\alpha \in [0,1)$, corresponding to an eigenvalue $-\alpha$ of $A\overline{A}$.

Comment: @  user208259 , OK for step 1. I add a step above.

Comment: Why do you need step 2 when you have steps 1 and 3?

Comment: Because step 2 simplifies step 3.

Comment: I used a different method. See below.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to give a complete proof of this result, which has a surprisingly conceptual basis, using the quaternions. I believe it can possibly be simplified further.

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the division ring of the quaternions. It contains $\mathbb{C}$ as a subring. View $\mathbb{H}$ as a left-$\mathbb{H}$-vector space over itself. An arbitrary endomorphism of $\mathbb{H}$ consists of right multiplication by some quaternion $w$, which can be written uniquely as $w = a + bj$ for some complex numbers $a$ and $b$. If we view $\mathbb{H}$ as a left-$\mathbb{C}$ vector space with basis $(1, j)$, then the matrix of this mapping is easily seen to be $$\begin{pmatrix}a & -\overline{b} \\ b & \overline{a} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now let $V = \mathbb{H}^n$, and let $f \colon V \to V$ be a left-$\mathbb{H}$-linear endomorphism of $V$. Let $v_1, v_2, \dots v_n$ be a basis of $V$ (which can be the standard basis). Then a basis of $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is given by $(v_1, jv_1, v_2, jv_2, \dots, v_n, jv_n)$. In view of the preceding remarks, the matrix of $f$ in this basis must be made up of $2 \times 2$ blocks of the form above. Now if we reorder the basis to be $(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n, jv_1, jv_2, \dots, jv_n$), then the matrix becomes one of the form
$$T = \begin{pmatrix}A & -\overline{B} \\ B & \overline{A} \end{pmatrix},$$
where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary $n \times n$ complex matrices. Furthermore, the foregoing arguments show that the $\mathbb{H}$-linearity of $f$ is equivalent to its matrix having this form.

Henceforth, the argument will be based on two facts:

1. The determinant of any matrix of the given form is a nonnegative real number.
2. We note that $$\det (I + A\overline{A}) = \det \begin{pmatrix} I & -\overline{A} \\ A & I \end{pmatrix}$$
   is the determinant of a matrix of the required form.

Point 2 follows from the factorization
  $$\begin{pmatrix} I & O \\ -A & I \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I & -\overline{A} \\ A & I \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} I & -\overline{A} \\ O & I+A\overline{A} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Point 1 is where I wonder if some improvements are possible, but here is a proof. Let $f \colon V \to V$ again be left-$\mathbb{H}$-linear, and let $T$ be its matrix as above.

First we prove that $\det T$ is a real number. The conjugate matrix
$$\overline{T} = \begin{pmatrix} \overline{A} & -B \\ \overline{B} & A \end{pmatrix}$$
can be obtained from $T$ in the following steps: exchange the first $n$ rows with the last $n$ rows; exchange the first $n$ columns with the last $n$ columns; multiply the bottom $n$ rows by $-1$; multiply the last $n$ columns by $-1$. It follows that $\det T = \det \overline{T} = \overline{\det T}$, hence $\det T$ is real.

Now, for any real number $\lambda$, what was said about $T$ is equally applicable to any matrix $T - \lambda I$, which is still of the required form. It follows therefore that the characteristic polynomial $\chi(\lambda)$ takes only real values for real $\lambda$, hence has real coefficients.

This shows that the non-real eigenvalues of $T$ occur in conjugate pairs (including multiplicities), and since $\det T$ is the product of its eigenvalues we need only check that negative real eigenvalues have even multiplicity. However, this is true for any real eigenvalue $\lambda$ (whether positive or negative), for the following reason.

The multiplicity of $\lambda$ is $\dim \ker (f - \lambda \operatorname{id})^{2n}$. Since $f$ is $\mathbb{H}$-linear, so too is $(f - \lambda \operatorname{id})^{2n}$. (That $\lambda$ is real is crucial for this, because left-multiplication by a *complex* number is not left-$\mathbb{H}$-linear, as $\mathbb{C}$ is not in the centre of $\mathbb{H}$.) Therefore the kernel of this operator is an $\mathbb{H}$-subspace of $V$, and it must therefore have *even* dimension over $\mathbb{C}$.