# A question about the determinant of a block matrix.

Tags: matrices, determinant

Suppose that $A，B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Is it right that
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\-\bar{B}&\bar{A}\end{pmatrix}\geq 0$$
If this is right, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By a continuity argument, you may assume that $A$ is nonsingular. Let $C=A^{-1}B$. Then
$$
\det\pmatrix{A&B\\ -\overline{B}&\overline{A}}
=\det\left[\pmatrix{A&0\\ 0&\overline{A}}\pmatrix{I&C\\ -\overline{C}&I}\right]
=|\det(A)|^2\det(I+C\overline{C}).
$$
For any complex square matrix $C$, all eigenvalues of $C\overline{C}$ that are not real nonnegative must occur in conjugate pairs (see D.C. Youla, [A normal form for a matrix under the unitary congruence group](http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1961-059-8), *Canad. J. Math.* 13, 1961, pp.694-704). Hence $\det(I+C\overline{C})\ge0$ (see also [Complex square matrices. Difficult proof.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1118795)) and the conclusion follows.